# inertia change direction to rtl , ltr

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vite, inertiajs

I'm working on a project multi-language inertia Vue 3 I made everything when choosing the language it gets the data-related translation, but I need to change the direction. Does anyone help me?

I need to change CSS file to change direction like this

```
@if(app()->getLocale() == 'en')
    /css/main.css
@else
    css/main-rtl.css
@endif
```